# Want to simulate {alt} key on BAT file

Tags: batch-file

i'm doing a batch file that opens notepad write my name and then simulate alt key (i will use it for another program, notepad just for test).
After this line i want to simulate the alt key for open navbar menu and then simulate click on file menu.

```
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "%username%"
```

How can i simulate alt key? Thank you

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off

set "username=Alexis"


start  /B "" "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe" 
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "%username%"

goto :EOF
@end    

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: for Windows `ALT` isn't a "key", more like a "modifier". Try `Alt`-`F` instead (or whatever your desired shortcut is), which is a valid keystroke.

Comment: Use `CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "%username%%%"` (add two percent signs after `%username%`). Just tested OK in Windows 8.1. See: [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx).